# android BroadcastReceiver doesn't initiliaze

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use broadcastreceiver with alarm manager but unfortunately it doesnt work on my phone (android 10). broadcastReceiver doesnt initiliaze. if someone help me, I will appriciate him/her

**BroadcastReceiver Class**

```
`public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Wake up",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("fffffgggg", "onReceive: reached broadcast");
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }`
```

**manifest for receiver**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Alarm" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">

        </receiver>
    </application>
```

**MainActivity class**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notifyintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, notifyintent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//update 30 seconds
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),30*1000, pIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide for action (some string), configure your broadcast receiver to process that action, and create a pending intent that fires that action.

It goes like this.

Manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Alarm" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MY_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Main activity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notifyintent = new Intent("MY_ACTION");
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, notifyintent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//update 30 seconds
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),30*1000, pIntent);
    }
```

Also, it's recommended to make sure you got the right action in `onReceive` function.

Comment: Shlomi Katriel thanks for your reply but problem seems different here. adding action to intent is probably help to handle different or multiple broadcastreceivers. Now I tried  'alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pIntent); '  it is working. I cant use setRepeating or setExacRepeating methods

Comment: Hi, I believe broadcast receivers only processes actions so you must set the action in the intent you fire and configure your manifest accordingly. About the other thing, have you tried `AlarmManager#setInexactRepeating`? See https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#examples-of-elapsed-real-time-alarms

Comment: adding action may help to get spesific action in broadcastreceiver but look like it is not necessary to use

Comment: As far as I know it's a must-have

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager is using Pending Intent as base. Pending intent it is a intent modification so for the first you must define action in your manifest, and give that value to Pending intent. For more detail you can read alarm manager google documentation, I hope I've been of help.

Comment: hi Rob Gas thanks for your answer. this issue is terribile. I found that battery optimization prevents setInexactRepeating and setRepeating working. when I disable battery optimization for my app and add REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission to manifest, I sarted to get messages from my broadcastReceiver repeatively https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/22807634.html article mentions the issue