# AlarmManager doesn't work on MIUI (and who knows where else)

Tags: android, android-notifications, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm, miui

My application gives user an option to schedule daily notifications on a specific time. I use `AlarmManager` to achieve this behavior.

On a click of a button I execute the following code:

```
val datetimeToAlarm = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
                /*datetimeToAlarm.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 21)
                datetimeToAlarm.set(MINUTE, 0)
                datetimeToAlarm.set(SECOND, 0)
                datetimeToAlarm.set(MILLISECOND, 0)*/

                NotificationHelper.createNotificationChannel(
                    requireContext(),
                    NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT,
                    false,
                    weather,
                    "Daily weather notifications for ${weather.cityName}"
                )

                NotificationHelper.scheduleNotification(
                    requireContext(),
                    datetimeToAlarm,
                    weather
                )
```

For testing purposes I do not set the exact time it must fire at just yet.

The two methods of `NotificationHelper` class that I use above:

```
fun createNotificationChannel(
            context: Context,
            importance: Int,
            showBadge: Boolean,
            data: Weather,
            description: String
        ) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                // Format: $placeId-$cityName
                val channelId = "${data.placeId}-${data.cityName}"
                val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Weather for ${data.cityName}", importance)
                channel.description = description
                channel.setShowBadge(showBadge)

                val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
                Log.v("Notifications", "Created channel $channelId")
            }
        }

fun scheduleNotification(context: Context, timeOfNotification: Calendar, data: Weather) {
            val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, "Weather for ${data.cityName}")
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, "Temperature: ${data.daily[0].temperature.min.roundToInt()}°/${data.daily[0].temperature.max.roundToInt()}°")
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, data.id)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PLACE_ID, data.placeId)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CITY_NAME, data.cityName)
            val pending =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, data.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            // Schedule notification
            val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val repeatInterval: Long = 1000 * 60 * 15 // 15 minutes
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNotification.timeInMillis, repeatInterval, pending)
            // start time is in AM/PM format
            Log.v("Notifications", "Scheduled notification id ${data.id} with start at " +
                    "${SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(timeOfNotification.timeInMillis)} and interval " +
                    SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(repeatInterval))
        }
```

Again, for testing purposes I set repeating interval to 15 minutes just to see if it works.

In my `BroadcastReciever`'s `onReceive` method I just call `createNotification` of my `NotificationHelper` class

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        // Deliver the notification.
        Log.v("Notifications", "Receiver received call")
        if (intent.extras == null) return
        val title = intent.getStringExtra(NotificationHelper.EXTRA_TITLE)!!
        val text = intent.getStringExtra(NotificationHelper.EXTRA_TEXT)!!
        val id = intent.getIntExtra(NotificationHelper.EXTRA_ID, -1)
        val placeId = intent.getStringExtra(NotificationHelper.EXTRA_PLACE_ID)
        val cityName = intent.getStringExtra(NotificationHelper.EXTRA_CITY_NAME)
        NotificationHelper.createNotification(
            context,
            title,
            text,
            "",
            "$placeId-$cityName",
            id
        )
    }
```

```
        fun createNotification(
            context: Context,
            title: String,
            message: String,
            bigText: String,
            channelId: String,
            id: Int,
            autoCancel: Boolean = true
        ) {

            Log.v("Notifications", "Fired notification creation with following parameters: $title, $message, $channelId, $id")
            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId).apply {
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                setContentTitle(title)
                setContentText(message)
                setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
                priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                setAutoCancel(autoCancel)

                val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
                setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            }
            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
            notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build())

        }
```

And of course, my receiver is registered in the manifest:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".utils.notifications.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

When I launch my app on an emulator API 30 and click the button, I get the following logs:

```
2021-03-06 20:13:11.615 11229-11229/com.calamity.weather V/Notifications: Created channel location_place-Mountain View
2021-03-06 20:13:11.626 11229-11229/com.calamity.weather V/Notifications: Scheduled notification id 1 with start at 2021-03-06 08:13:11 and interval 01-01 03:15:00
2021-03-06 20:13:16.624 11229-11229/com.calamity.weather V/Notifications: Receiver received call
2021-03-06 20:13:16.624 11229-11229/com.calamity.weather V/Notifications: Fired notification creation with following parameters: Weather for Mountain View, Temperature: 9°/15°, location_place-Mountain View, 1
```

My notification is shown right away, and if I go and close my app, it will be delivered again after 15 minutes.

However, if I launch it on a real device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 9, MIUI Global 12.0.4, API 29), on a click of a button my logs are:

```
2021-03-06 20:16:50.945 19673-19673/com.calamity.weather V/Notifications: Created channel ChIJiQHsW0m3j4ARm69rRkrUF3w-Mountain View
2021-03-06 20:16:50.951 19673-19673/com.calamity.weather V/Notifications: Scheduled notification id 2 with start at 2021-03-06 08:16:50 and interval 01-01 03:15:00
```

As you can see, alarm is not fired even if my app is still in the foreground, not to mention if I swipe it out of recent apps list. So the questions are:

- Why doesn't it fire even with the app still running?
- How do I make it behave how it's supposed to and deliver my notifications even with closed app?

I did my research and found out that Chinese ROMs aggressively restrict Services and Jobs, but it seems like `AlarmManager` should work regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hı Calamity I encountered same problem yesterday. Also I am using Redmi Note 9. After searching all net, I found that **setRepeating** and **setInexactRepeating** methods doesnt work. if you change `manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNotification.timeInMillis, repeatInterval, pending)`  to `manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNotification.timeInMillis, pending)`  you will see that your codes work. to work  **setRepeating** and **setInexactRepeating** methods, you need to disable Battery optimization for your app after that open your app you will see that those methods will work. Also here my asked question [android BroadcastReceiver doesn't initiliaze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66497569/android-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-initiliaze)

Comment: This actually worked! Thanks for your help, been stuck with this for a while. That's a shame that workarounds like this are required though.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working on my Xiaomi Mi9. After some time my app and foreground service is killed "PowerChecker.Controller com.miui.powerkeeper                 W  autoKillApp, calling ProcessManager uid = 10523, pkg = ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1" and once the app/service is killed the alarm is not triggered anymore.